# Execute git cmd via node.js on windows fails with err

Tags: windows, git, node.js, environment-variables

git is installed on windows and works from any directory (it is in System path)

```
var child_process = require('child_process');
child_process.exec('git --version', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
  // stdout is correct - git version 1.7.11.msysgit.1
  // but err is not null
  // err is [Error: Command failed: ] killed: false, code: 1, signal: null }      
}
```

What can cause this?

Comment: i dont have git installed on windows but perhaps `git \version` is the proper syntax?

Comment: git --version works to on windows. I think it can not find git but I don't understand why

Comment: how irritating! perhaps as a workaround you might pass `{env:{PATH:"C:\path to\node"}}` as the options argument to `process.exec()` as described in [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback). other than that I have no experience with Windows environment variables, thus no further ideas :/

Comment: It's in my computer's path (on Windows), and your code worked for me. I did have to make sure that I restarted the shell that I was using for my NodeJS development. `stdout = git version 1.8.3.msysgit.0`

Comment: Actually - restarting the shell might have been the solution, not my snippet... I think that the shell does not source environment variables dynamically. So if you didn't restart the shell between adding the dir to Windows PATH and posting the question, remove my snippet and see if it still works

Comment: I think the error is clear: 'killed'. Someway or the other, the command is executed as expected, but the git command stopped, making node.js think that the process was prematurely killed. Try running that in a command shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue using Windows 7 with msysgit. Two things seem to solve the issue.

First, verify that your `Path` system variable includes a path to the Git bin directory, and *not* the cmd directory:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin
```

Next, verify you have a recent version of msysgit. I've verified the issue as solved with version `1.8.4-preview`:

https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list

Restart your shell and try again.

Comment: Wow, this just happened to me after installing newest Git.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can pass `{env:{PATH:"C:\path to\node"}}` as the options argument to `process.exec(cmd, opts, callback)` as described in docs. I am surprised that the Windows path doesn't carry over but have no explanation why.

Comment: I've added in OP, there is not problem with PATH. It just can not execute git without err.